# How to replace a green LED with a red one in a simple transistor switch?

Tags: led, bjt

I am designing four traffic lights that I can control with a single digital switch. When the signal is 1, two traffic lights should be green, and the other two red, and they should reverse when the digital signal is 0. I'm using a simple transistor switch to achieve this:

[image]

This one works in the simulation, but I tried it on the breadboard, and it won't work properly unless I swap the green LED with the red one and vice versa.
Otherwise, the red LED stays on regardless of the applied base voltage, while the green one stays off.

Moreover, the whole implementation doesn't work in the simulation. Only the first and the third gates switch properly. The second and the fourth ones have the above-mentioned issue:

[image]

Now, I'm aware that the red and green LEDs have different forward voltages (1.7V for red and 2.2V for green), but I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: It'll work for circuit one because the voltage at the anode of LG1 will dragged down below the turn on voltage for LG1 when Q2 is saturated.

Comment: If you think about what the minimum voltage on the collector of Q1 can be, taking into account the voltage drop across the LED and the transistor, you will see why the red LED is always on.

Comment: "I'm using a simple TTL switch " no such thing....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using both NPN and PNP transistors is probably your best bet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f62aRy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or this way is more elegant.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frU8St.png)</sup>

**ADDITION**

If you must drive this with a single pole switch, you should probably make the signal more active.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDKIOi.png)</sup>

Comment: Wondering whether using PNP as pull up would be better here. Like we use pmos instead of nmos as pull up in MOSFET circuits ?

Comment: @MITURAJ there are numerous ways to do it.. two is my limit for freebies ;) Not sure what you mean though... I did it this way round so there is no shoot-thru and the LEDs are low enough Vf for 5V to cover the rail offsets.

Comment: I mean, in MOSFET inverter we use pmos as pull up instead of nmos. Because if we use nmos as pull up, only Vdd -Vth is obtained across the load. Is there anything like that in the BJT inverter of second figure ?

Comment: @Trevor Thanks for the input! Unfortunately, none of those two circuits seem to work. The first one only connects/disconnects the red LED from the circuit. The green led is always on and always uses the same amount of power. The second circuit provides too low current (~2.5 mA) for the red LED.

Comment: @user2210558 huh? They should both work fine. You need to adjust the resistors in the second one to match the voltages available and currents required.

Comment: OH wait... YOu said TTL,, you are just using a switch...

Comment: Maybe because the inputs to the transistors are floating at base. I think it has to be pulled up/down using resistors.

Comment: @user2210558 sigh... I saw TTL, I did not realize you were using just switches.... anyhow, I added pull-downs, but you would be better using more active signals or a two pole switch.

Comment: I tried simulating the PNP side from the first circuit, and it won't do anything. The collector voltage is 0.7V, so there's a whopping 4.3V drop on the transistor itself, regardless of the switch state

Comment: @user2210558 see updates...

Comment: @Trevor oh, it works now, thanks! but I'm still not sure by what you mean, isn't TTL just boolean logic with bipolar transistors? Isn't it the case here? (NOT gate)

Comment: @user2210558 A TTL signal is a very specific set of voltages and currents. What you have is just a floating line with a switched in pull-up.

Comment: An ignoramus asks: How do you get away with Q2 not having a base current limiting resistor in the last scenario when the switch is closed? What am I missing here?

Comment: @DiBosco oops... this is what happens when you get frustrated and rush stuff....

Comment: I think you still have a problem.  The voltage drop across R2 affects the base voltage of the second transistor and turns it on when it shouldn't be.  Actually, with the base pins tied together, their voltage should obey both (Vb <= 0.7 V) and (5V - Vb <= 0.7V) simultaneously, for which there is no solution.  You'll have a very large current sourced by the base of Q2 and sunk into the base of Q1.  You need to unshare R2.

Comment: @BenVoigt yup.... it's been a long morning....

Answer (score 9):

Since the LEDs you are switching are different colours they have different forward voltages. We can do a nice trick with this.

[image] [image]

*Figure 1. Switching between two LEDs with an N.O. contact and the load-line explanation. Source: [1 GPIO, multiple LEDs](http://lednique.com/gpio-tricks/1-gpio-multiple-leds/).*

The intersection of the load-line graph shows us what voltage and current we can expect on each LED type with that value resistor.

- In Figure 1a the green LED is on by default and the load-line shows that we can expect about 16 mA through it and 2.1 V across it.
- If we switch on the red the forward voltage will drop to 1.75 or 1.8 V. At that voltage the green will pass only a couple of mA and should turn off or go dim.

If you want the red on by default then we add in D1 to induce a little more voltage drop. D1 + L3 = 0.7 + 1.75 = 2.45 V. When the switch is closed the green LED will cause the LED voltage to drop to 2.1 V and the red will go out.

If S2 is replaced with a logic output the voltage might not be sufficiently high enough so additional diodes may be required in the default leg.

[image]

*Figure 2. The advanced electronic solution uses a transistor! Source: [1 GPIO dual LED common cathode](http://lednique.com/gpio-tricks/1-gpio-dual-led-common-cathode/).*

The GPIO in Figure 2 powers L1 directly when high. When low L1 turns off and Q1 turns on, powering L2. Note that the GPIO must be capable of driving L1 directly.

<sub>The links are to articles written by me.</sub>